# CSS line spacing problem

Tags: css, element

why is the word BESTSELLER skipping a line... there is nothing in the code telling it to do so? (forgive me -- here is the link http://u.neighborrow.com/)

```
      <div class="input text required">
                <label for="ItemItem"></label><input type="text" id="ItemItem" value="" maxlength="255" style="font-size: 25px; width: 200px; margin: 5px 0pt;" name="data[Item][item]">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" style="font-size: 22px" />
            </div>


            <?php echo $form->end(); ?>
            Tips: <span style="font-size: 13px; position: relative; top: -2px"> Taking a trip? Want to try something before you buy it? <br > Have a project or event coming up? Want to see who has a copy of that bestseller?</span>
            <br />
            <?= $form->create('Item', array('action' => 'indextest')); ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: You might try pasting your emitted code, instead of your source.  It's much easier to see what's going on.  Try to include the entire HTML; or provide a link to see it in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what you mean by "skipping a line". Perhaps a link to the live code would help. But I did notice you have more closing div tags than opening.

EDIT: It appears the surrounding div has a computed line height of 30px. But the subject span has a line height of 18px.  So, when the span takes up an entire line, it displays at the 18px line height. But when it only takes up a partial line, the 30px line height is applied to the remainder of that line, and this causes the last line to display at the larger 30px line height.  Try setting the 18px line height at the parent div, or set the span to be display: block, so that the larger line height is not displayed in-line.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add **display:block** to your span or replace the span width any block-level element such as `<p>` or `<div>`. In a semantic world you should use a `<p>` ;)

Also you should try to prevent inline-styles.